# How to fix cropping of file names in windows 11 file explorer list view?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Since I updated from W10 to W11 (10.0.2261) file names in the File Explorer list view are displayed with the descenders of letters cropped off. In the attached screenshot the file extension that looks like "ipa" is actually "jpg".

What setting or other means should I use to correct this?

I have tried settings->Personalization->fonts but it seems only to control what fonts are loaded into the font menus as opposed to changing what is seen in the W11 user interface.

I have tried Settings->Accessibility->text size and this does change the text size but does not eliminate the cropping.

I have tried Settings->System->Display reducing the scale to 125% which is actually less than the recommended setting for this laptop with its 96 dpi screen, but this does not fix the problem.

I have reviewed File Explorer -> options but didn't find anything relevant.[image]

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).